# Именительный от "[Россияне]  обоего пола".

Tags: грамматика

Набрел на сочетание типа "84% россиян  **обоего пола** считают, что...".

Корректность "*обоего пола*" сомнений не вызывает. То, что с современных позиций это родительный падеж единственного числа, - тоже. 
Прочие косвенные падежи "*обоего*" (*обоему полу, обоим полом, об обоем поле*) - уже под большим вопросом.
А именительный (?*обоий*) современного носителя просто вводит в ступор.

Была ли такая форма и как она образовалась?
А если "*обоий*" не существовало, то как появилось "обоего"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именительный от ***обоего*** (по Зализняку) -- ****обой***. Но вот применялась ли когда-нибудь форма им. п. в русском языке -- не знаю.

Зализняк («Русское именное словоизменение») относит слово ***обоего*** к словам, встречающимся только в устойчивых выражениях, причём к таким, где падеж данного слова фиксирован: ****обой*** *(обоего пола, обоего рода).*

> Корректность *"обоего пола"* сомнений не
>   вызывает. То, что **с современных**
>   позиций это родительный падеж
>   единственного числа, - тоже.

И не только с современных…

Из "Тетради русской грамматики для русских" Половцова Виктора Андреевича, изданной в 1835 году:

[image]

**P.S.**

**Нашёл у Буслаева ("Историческая грамматика русского языка"):**

*Затерянный въ употребленіи имен. падежъ ед. числа муж. р., вѣроятно, былъ **обый** или **обой**...*

[image]

Comment: Согласен. 
Хотя реконструкция обой/обый не бесспорна, остальное вполне убедительно. На Буслаева у меня пороху не хватило посмотреть.
Он есть в сети, не знаете?

Да, что касательно "современных позиций", я не имел в виду, что раньше могло быть как-то по-другому. Речь как раз о том, что другую трактовку просто трудно представить.

Comment: К Славе. Научи меня, пжста, как вставлять книжный текст.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что образовалось это не от именительного падежа. Возможны языковые ситуации, когда нужно напр. кратко ответить на вопрос: какого пола (люди собрались)? Если отвечать в том же падеже: и того, и другого; разного, всякого. "И того, и другого" в именительном падеже: "и тот, и другой" = "оба". Есть потребность обойтись одним словом, но прилагательные "разного" и "всякого", хотя и выражают близкий к нужному смысл, допускают многовариантность полов (они "неточны"), отсюда стремление образовать прилагательное от "оба" в том же падеже: "обоего". Как и в случае "разного", это слово не порождает некоего "общего" пола, а указывает на смешанный гендерный состав группы людей. В именительном падеже можно обойтись другими краткими формами (оба пола), поэтому нет потребности образовывать что-то от "обоего". В итоге, можно рассматривать это прилагательное с его уникальным падежом как уточнение относительно "разного" в данной конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Каким образом желание сказать что-то не в том падеже может так повлиять на грамматику, что появляется "изолированная" форма для единственного падежа? 
Давайте так. Слово "обоего" на ваш вкус нормативное? Если нет, обсуждать тут нечего.
Если нормативное, то какова его исходная форма? В орфоэпическом словаре в каком гнезде искать?

Comment: Исходная форма (в моём понимании это то, от чего слово "хронологически" произошло) - не именительный падеж. Видимо, можно здесь образовывать формы именительного падежа (Славой гипотетические варианты найдены в словарях, но они там без примеров реального применения). Они могли никогда не применяться за ненадобностью, неблагозвучием и т.п. Мы ведь избегаем напр. слова "пылесошу", но запросто говорим в 3 лице "пылесосит" - слово, более далёкое от того, которое можно принять за "исходную форму".

Comment: О нормативности: на мой взгляд, вне данного контекста "обоего" в большинстве случаев нельзя применить ("обоего вида /смысла и пр./", даже если растолковано, какие два имеют в виду). Но могу предположить допустимость других исключений: не только "пол", но и "род" или "толк" - в оговоренных случаях, когда обозначены две альтернативы или противоположности. "Высказывались соображения обоего рода: и теоретические, и практические." Здесь с множественным числом получается даже менее складно (обоих родов или толков).