# Лица обоего пола

Tags: словосочетания

В научных публикациях часто встречаю словосочетание "лица обоего пола". По этому поводу в редакции нашего журнала мнения разделились. Некоторые считают, что корректнее писать "лица обоих полов" либо же как-то перефразировать. Другие полагают, что хотя в природе и не существует "лиц обоего пола" (по крайней мере, они если и существуют, то совсем в другом смысле), тем не менее такое словосочетание является общеупотребительным и, следовательно, допустимым. А как считаете вы?
Лично мне претит употребление подобных словосочетаний, но могу ли я как рецензент указывать на использование такого словосочетания, как на ошибку?
Заранее признателен за ответ.

Comment: Почему же научных? Гончаров, Островский не брезговали... http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%E1%EE%E5%E3%EE+%EF%EE%EB%E0

Comment: Встречаю в научных публикациях, потому что читаю именно их...

Comment: Мнения в редакции разделились по этому поводу?

Comment: Мнения разделились по поводу допустимости и уместности использования названного сочетания слов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Именительный от "\[Россияне\]  обоего пола".](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47093/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)  Вопрос № 300175

Доброго времени суток!  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: **"представители обоих полов" или "представители обоего пола".** Заранее большое спасибо!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Возможны оба варианта. ***Обоего пола*** — рудимент старого книжного русского языка.

2) Малый академический словарь

**обоего**
обо́ему, обо́им, об обо́ем (**им. и вин. нет**), числ. м. и ср. **устар.**

И того и другого.

◊
**лица обоего пола** — лица мужского и женского пола.

3) Обсуждение похожей темы **на сайте**

[Именительный от "[Россияне]  обоего пола".](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47093/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0)

4) Частотность употребления в Нацкорпусе за все время:  810 (обоего) и 210 (обоих).